# Animating a 3-D arrow given the vector's x, y, and z components as a function of time

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, animation

I am trying to show how a vector `M` varies over time.  I have the following code:

```
Mx={4.74124,13.1038,33.0248,19.7323,24.5952,30.1253,27.9521,29.4089,28.0574,29.277};
My={-18.2975,-7.42215,-4.23518,-9.88457,-8.96098,-8.22531,-9.6019,-9.18352,-9.06551,-9.29939};
Mz={-0.12887,-7.57926,-1.4561,-1.59703,-4.53247,-2.09772,-2.91711,-3.56798,-2.6221,-3.48453};

Animate[

Graphics3D[{
Blue,Arrow[Tube[{{0,0,0},{Mx[[i]],My[[i]],Mz[[i]]}}]]
},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"},Axes],

{i,1,Length[Mx],1}]
```

(In actuality, my lists `Mx`, `My`, and `Mz` are much longer, but the shorter lists above reproduce the error behavior.)

I get the following error:

> An improperly formatted option was encountered while reading a
>   Graphics3DBox.  The option was not in the form of a rule.

Do you know how I can fix this?  I do not understand which option "was not in the form of a rule."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a stray argument in the `Graphics3D` function (`Axes`).
Also, you probably want a fixed `PlotRange`.  Try:

```
Animate[
 Graphics3D[{Blue, 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Mx[[i]], My[[i]], Mz[[i]]}}]]}, 
    Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
    PlotRange -> ({Min@# - 5, Max@# + 5} & /@ {Mx, My, Mz})],
 {i, 1, Length[Mx], 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

In the future try to debug your own code.  You would have seen the same problem without the `Animate` function if you tried that.  Also, the error code suggests that something is wrong with the graphics options, which should have directed your attention to the arguments of `Graphics3D`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have voted to close my question as being too localized.  (I missed my silly mistake.)

Comment: Or maybe I should delete the question?  What do you think?

Comment: @Andrew I'd rather have the points but I'm OK with it. :-)

Comment: I think the fixed plot range is a reasonable question.  The stray `Axes` that was causing the error can just be edited out of the question.

Comment: @Andrew see Brett's comment above.

Answer (score 8):

You may also play some tricks:

```
h = Transpose[Table[{Cos@t, Sin@t, t^.1}, {t, 0, 8 Pi, .1}]];
d = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ h;

Manipulate[
 Show[
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, Through@d@t}]]}, Axes -> True, 
              AxesLabel -> {x,y,z}, PlotRange -> ({1.1 Min@#, 1.1 Max@#} & /@ h)],

  ParametricPlot3D[Through@d@v, {v, 1, t}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, Hue[z]]]],
 {t, 1.001, Length@First@h}
]
```

[Full Movie Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwH7h7sOJeo)

[image]

**Edit**

Fancier, by using InterpolatingFunctio[] properties:

```
<< DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`

pltIntFun[d:{_InterpolatingFunction ..}]:=Module[{pRange,manipDomain,k = (Max@# - Min@#) 10^-4 &},

   pRange      = { Min@# - k@#, Max@# + k@#} & /@ Through@d@"ValuesOnGrid";
   manipDomain = Join[{t}, ({ Min@# + k@#, Max@#} & /@ Through@d@"Domain")[[1]]];

   Manipulate[Show[
     Graphics3D[
      {Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, Through@d@t}]]}, 
       Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> pRange],

     ParametricPlot3D[Through@d@v, {v, 1, t}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, Hue[z]]]],
                      Evaluate@manipDomain]];


d = Interpolation[#,InterpolationOrder->1] &/@ Transpose[Table[{Cos@t,Sin@t,t^.1}, {t,0,8 Pi,.1}]];
pltIntFun[d]
```